# UML Diagram in Python 3.7

Tags: python, object, uml

[image]

This UML diagram (see link) should be implemented in Python. I'm not quite sure, how to implement the functionalities with direct associations 0,1 and * and * and 1*. I also don't really know how to implement the attribute `total_representation`, which, as you can see in the diagram, is static. 
"WiMi" is the german word for "Teaching Assistant".

My attempt (so far):

```
class Member:
    name = ""
    self.presentation = []

    def __init__(self, name, id_number):
        self.name = name
        self.id_numer = id_number

    def print_name(self):
        print ("Name = " + self.name)

    def print_id_number (self):
        print ("ID = " + id_number)


class Professor(Member):
    def __init__(self, name, id_number, _cost_center_no):
        self.name = name
        self._cost_center_no = _cost_center_no

    def get_cost_center_no (self):
        return _cost_center_no

    #def get_cost_center_no(self):
        # Wie Kostenstellennummer umsetzen?

    #def do_study(self):
        #print ("Student studies")

class WiMi(Member):
    def __init__(self, name, id_number):
        self.name = name
#####Präsentation Klasse (Aggregation, gerichtet)

class Presentation:

    def __init__ (self, title, date):
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.date = date

    def change_date (self, date):
        self.date = date
###Reserch Group Klasse

class Research_Group:

    def __init__ (self, name, total_representation)
        self.name = name
        self.total_representation = total_representation

    def get_members (self):
        return self.members 

    def get_head (self)
        return self.head

    def set_head (self, head):
        self.head = head

    def add_member (self, member):
        self.vl.member (vl)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are a couple of issues with your diagram:

- Instead of directed associations you are encouraged to use dot notation.
- The navigation is questionable. The research group likely has one Professor as head and any number associated "WiMi"s.
- Naming the associations as you did it is a bit pointless. Rather you should use roles (and accordingly the dot notation to identify owned properties).
- The shared aggregation has no defined semantics as per UML specs. It wouldn't make sense if it were composite. It's likely an association (a Member has a Presentation). Probably it should as well be an association class to link it with the ResearchGroup. I wouldn't know why this should be static at all (probably wrong thinking in lines with the missing association class for Presentation).

Since you are implementing it in Python the multiplicities can be simplified.

- `0..1` means you have a simple variable which can take `None` or a value (there's no type checking in Python).
- `1` means it must not be `None`.
- `*` or `n..m` means you have an array (just initialize it with `[]`).
- Static variables are kind of undefined in Python. You could put them on a global scope as some kind of compromise.

Comment: Thanks your help, Thomas Kilian.

Comment: I didn't make the diagramm. My professor did it . We should just write a python programm, based on his diagramm.

Comment: Just as a side note: you should run your code through Python. It has (a) bug(s). Not sure about Py3, but the super initialization is missing.

Comment: We shoul also catch errors in this, e.g. when you an __init__ takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given. Should I work with try_expect in this case? I tried it, but didn't worked.

Comment: Sorry, but Python lectures would take us away. If you got specific Python issues, ask another question.

Comment: I think the aggregation is ok, assuming the Presentation is an event (it's hard for a presentation to be given without members) rather than a document etc. Presentation has a set of Members. The use of the {abstract} constraint rather than italics does however indicate UML 2, so dot notation would be consistent i agree.

Comment: @muszeo It's a shared aggregation and that has no defined semantics (see box on p. 110 of UML 2.5).